# Order address update in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to update shipping and billing address for an order in Magento2. Here is my code below.

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $order;
    protected $orderRepoInterface;
    protected $orderAddressInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderAddressRepositoryInterface $orderRepoInterface,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface $orderAddressInterface
    ) {
        $this->_order = $order;
        $this->_orderRepoInterface = $orderRepoInterface;
        $this->_orderAddressInterface = $orderAddressInterface;
    }

    public function saveShipping(){
        $shipAddress = $this->_orderRepoInterface->get('shipping address id');
            if($shipAddress->getId())
            {
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setFirstname('name');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setCountryId('US');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setRegion('region');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setPostcode('code');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setCompany('company name');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setStreet('some address');
                $this->_orderAddressInterface->setCity('city');
                //print_r($shipAddress->getData());
                $shipAddress->save($this->_orderAddressInterface);
            }
    }
```

But its not saving anything. Any idea about `which class i should use or why its not saving any data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, case you need use

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository
```

instead of `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderAddressRepositoryInterface`

### Final class:

```
protected $repositoryAddress;
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository $repositoryAddress
    ) {
        $this->repositoryAddress= $repositoryAddress;
    }

    public function saveShipping(){
        $shipAddress = $this->repositoryAddress->get('shipping address id');
            if($shipAddress->getId())
            {
                $shipAddress->setFirstname('name');
                //$shipAddress->setCountryId('US');
                //$shipAddress->setRegion('region');
                $shipAddress->setPostcode('code');
                $shipAddress->setCompany('company name');
                $shipAddress->setStreet('some address');
                $shipAddress->setCity('city');
                //print_r($shipAddress->getData());
                 $this->repositoryAddress->save($shipAddress);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Not working at my end.

Comment: setRegion() is not working

Comment: HI @Amit, why  //$shipAddress->setRegion('region'); is commented? we need to update region as well